# How to assign actions to UINavigationItem backBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to find a way to stop some of the processes within a detail controller (and let the user know that this is happening) when the back button in the navigation bar is pressed. However, I can't find a way to implement these changes when the button is pressed.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to raise a user alert/notification before going back, you are really going to have to create your own back bar button item and assign it to `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`.

You need to hide the default button using:

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Then add a target to your new button which does your process cleanup and raises an alert. In the alert handler, pop the controller once the user has acknowledged the alert.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and easiest way is to use custom back button like below;

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(actionBack)];

    [self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:barButtonItem];
}

-(void)actionBack{
    //PopViewController
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like any other button.

Put this in the .m file.

```
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {

    //actions

 }
```

Then control drag from the UINavigationBarButton to the IBAction